# How do I add a decimal value to a value in my bash script?

Tags: bash, decimal, tail

I'm grabbing the tail of my output file and then want to add 0.000001 to that value.

So far I've tried it this way:

```
offset=0.000001

time=$(($(`tail -1 speed.txt1`) + $offset))
```

Comment: please update the question with sample inputs and the desired output; does `tail -1 speed.txt1` return an integer, float, e-notation number, something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash itself does not have any floating point ability. You need to use another tool to get a float result in the shell.

Given:

```
cat file
1
2
3
```

You can use `bc` for floating point in the shell:

```
offset='0.000001'
printf "%s+%s\n" $(tail -1 file) "$offset" | bc
3.000001
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk -v offset="$offset" 'END{printf "%.7f\n", $1+offset}' file
3.000001
```

Since `bc` does not understand scientific notation (ie, `1.3E6`) and you can still normalize that with `printf` in the shell:

```
x=1.33E6
printf "%f\n" "$x"
1330000.000000
```

And *then* pass to `bc`:

```
offset="1e-6"
x=1.33E6
printf "%f+%f\n" "$x" "$offset"
1330000.000000+0.000001

printf "%f+%f\n" "$x" "$offset" | bc
1330000.000001
```